# Send emails in a non-interactive way in OS X

Tags: macos, script, apple-mail

I am using Mail.app in OS X 10.7. In a text file I have a list with 500 different email addresses, extracted from my address book, each one in a different line.

I would like to send some christmas. So I prepared a text template and I would like to send same text in an email to each recipient, just to each one. So I wonder if using some scripting this could be done in a non-interactive way in OS X. In Linux I think this could be done using "mutt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the body of the message is the same, then the best and easiest way to do this is to just copy and paste all the addresses into the BCC field (which you may need to unhide: *View → Bcc Address Field*). You can just copy and paste the contents of the whole text file, and Mail will detect the addresses properly.

Doing it this way means you're only sending out one email to your server, but each recipient sees it as addressed solely to them, and can't see anyone else's addresses.

That said, if you really want to automate this, I came up with an AppleScript for you. Open **AppleScript Editor** and paste in this code:

```
set theAddressFile to (choose file with prompt "Select Addresses File")
set theTextFile to (choose file with prompt "Select Message Body File")

-- read each line into a list, discarding newline at end of file
set theEmails to read theAddressFile using delimiter (ASCII character 10)

set theBodyText to read theTextFile

tell application "Mail"
    repeat with anEmail in theEmails
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"My Subject", content:theBodyText, visible:false}
        tell theNewMessage
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:anEmail}
            send
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

When run, it will prompt you for two files — the first one for the addresses (one per line, nothing else or it will break), and the second one is the body text. It will then send (using Mail.app) one email to each address. You'll want to change the subject in the code (currently `My Subject`) to something appropriate.

Comment: Excellent! I will test it and let you know, great work.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason a standard BCC wouldn't suffice? It's more or less designed for this sort of situation.

Comment: When I do that, the receiver sees that there is something on the BCC